# How to set css to more selectors when one of it is $(this)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to set background color using jquery for 2 selectors:

```
$('#selector1, #selector2').css('background-color', '#dcf0ff');
```

This is working, but how to do it, when one of selector is `$(this)`?

```
function() {
   $(this, '#element2').css('background-color', '#dcf0ff');
}
```

This is not working for none of selectors, and no errors are shown in the console.

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).add('#element2').css('background-color', '#dcf0ff')`

Comment: can you post a minimal amount of relevant code, please? it is hard to tell what "this" is with what you have posted.

Comment: the jQuery object accepts 2 parameters, which is why it's not throwing an error. Using comma delimit like you are is not what you think it's doing like above.

Comment: @j08691 thank you, I didnt know about method `add`. Its working.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll add that as an answer then.

Comment: @Jesse the code I posted is pretty much enough to understand my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an element to a selector via jQuery's [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$(this).add('#element2').css('background-color', '#dcf0ff')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use two statements:

```
$('#element2').css('background-color', '#dcf0ff');
$(this).css('background-color', '#dcf0ff');
```

Or, if the CSS is long and you don't want two, repetitive statements, add its `id` (supposing it has one).

```
$("#element2, #" + this.attr("id")).css('background-color', '#dcf0ff');
```

Comment: @Legionar No problem!